# Expectation of $e^{i\alpha H}$

Tags: matrices, random-matrices, matrix-exponential, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I have $3\times 3$ a matrix $A$ defined as

$$A=e^{i\alpha H}, $$

with $H$ a  $3\times 3$ random Hermitian matrix, and $\alpha\in[0,\infty]$. I am trying to determine two things: Can we say anything on the expectation of $A$ in terms of the statistics of $H$? What conditions do $H$ need to satisfy so that the expectation of $A$ is diagonal?

Numerically I find that if the elements of $H$ have zero mean then the expectation of $A$ is diagonal. But I would like to know the general conditions for this (and why), and an explicit expression in terms of the statistics of $H$, if it exists!

Comment: This doesn’t seem true at all. For example, if $H$ is chosen uniformly from the two matrices $±\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 2i & -i \\ -2i & 0 & 2i \\ i & -2i & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $α = π$, then $H$ has zero mean but $\mathrm E[A] = \frac19\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1 & 4 & 8 \\ 4 & -7 & 4 \\ 8 & 4 & -1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the counter-example. In my tests I used H with identically distributed elements taken in either a Gaussian or a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible reason why your expectation is diagonal under uniform or gaussian distribution.

Let $S$ denote the matrix
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then the distribution of $H$ is invariant under conjugation by $S$, so
$$\mathbb{E} e^{i\alpha H} = \mathbb{E} e^{i\alpha S^{-1}HS} = \mathbb{E} S^{-1}e^{i\alpha H}S = S^{-1} \mathbb{E} e^{i\alpha H} S.$$
As conjugation by $S$ negates the elements at $(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)$, we conclude that the elements at those points of $\mathbb{E} e^{i\alpha H}$ are zero. Similarly, by studying
$$S' = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
We conclude that if your distribution is invariant under conjugation by $S$ and $S'$, then the expectation $\mathbb{E} e^{i\alpha H}$ is diagonal.